# How to catch form WM_NCCalcSize from inside a Delphi custom component

Tags: delphi, components

Is it possible to control or redirect the WM_NCCalcSize and WM_NCHitTest events of a form from within a procedure of a custom component?

I have already been able to redirect the Paint and Resize events of the form but now I need to handle the WM_NCCalcSize and WM_NCHitTest events from procedures of a custom component.

These procedures control the size of the Caption bar on the form or simply hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those messages are sent directly to the Form's window procedure. So the component would have to subclass the Form to intercept them. For instance, by using the [`GetParentForm()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.GetParentForm) function to get a pointer to the Form, and then replacing its [`WindowProc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.WindowProc) property with a custom handler.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, I was so mired in sub-classifications and redirects that I forgot the main thing. WindwProc's suggestion has been perfect.